# Prevent overlapping divs in css

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5

I have a div `checkbox-container` inside a loop and I'm trying to use `position:absolute` to make them not interfere other elements.

But the problem is all the divs (like 20 divs) are in the same position I have tried to use `left, bottom, top` and others still not working. I have no idea why this doesn't work. Can anyone help me please?

Edit: I use position absolute because if I click select then the checkbox pops up in each product without overlapping but they destroy `<p><b>Available : {{$product->stock}} In Stock</b></p>` style that is why I want to use `position:absolute`

Blade

```
<button class="Select-Deselect" type="button">Select</button>

@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="checkbox-container" style="display:none;">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{$product->id}}" name="checked[]"></label><br />
           </div>
      </div>
<p><b>Available : {{$product->stock}} In Stock</b></p>
@endforeach
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$(".Select-Deselect").click( function(e) {
  if ($(this).html() == "Select") {
    $(".checkbox-container").css('display', 'block');
    $(this).html('Deselect');
  } else {
    $(".checkbox-container").css('display', 'none');
    $(this).html('Select');
  }
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear why you are using position:absolute.  If you reset back to no position or float at all on these elements, what change do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Still not sure why you would need an **absolute** position on those divs. You're telling every div with a class `checkbox-container` to have **the same** position. Try to place a `<div>` container around your `@foreach` and use absolute position on that div container and remove the absolute position from `.checkbox-container`

Comment: They are overlapping because you are using `position: absolute`. If you remove the styling, they don't interfere at all. https://jsfiddle.net/1guq7ma2/

What is the goal? How would you like them to display - if you can clarify that, we should be able to help.

Comment: Okay I will edit my question @vansch

Comment: One of those questions that IMHO should only be answered with “please go and find yourself a tutorial that explains some CSS layouting basics.” We are not here to give beginner tutorials.

Comment: I'm not a beginner but I"m just stuck maybe I didn't clarify enough @CBroe

Comment: hey @user11710915 is this wrapper thing in my example what you need?

Comment: Let me try your example @Kresimir Pendic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wrapper element needs `relative` position, check example

```css
/* top wrapper element needs > position: relative !! */
.wrapper{
  position: relative
}
.checkbox-container{
  position: absolute
}
.wrapper div:nth-child( 1 ){ top: 10px; left: 10px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 2 ){ top: 20px; left: 20px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 3 ){ top: 30px; left: 30px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 4 ){ top: 40px; left: 40px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 5 ){ top: 50px; left: 50px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 6 ){ top: 60px; left: 60px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 7 ){ top: 70px; left: 70px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 8 ){ top: 80px; left: 80px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 9 ){ top: 90px; left: 90px }
.wrapper div:nth-child( 10 ){ top: 100px; left: 100px }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox"></label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks at-least I can use this example to fix my problem @ Kresimir Pendic

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position:absolute` the said elements won't be affected by or affect the flow of webpage, therefore all divs will be in the same place and you wont achieve your goal whatever it might be, reply so I can see what you're aiming for